# What do I do when my game is rejected on CrazyGames

Tags: unity

My game got rejected on CrazyGames. I think it is because of thease reasons

1. Game is too hard
   The game rule is simply moving the car NEAR the flag. And beginners might just swipe the screen from the car to the flag. Which gives to much momentum so it occurs game over.
2. Game is too simple
   Crazygames might played few levels and I think it was too easy.
   There are ramps, and other obstacles, and even coins to make the game more fun.
   But they might didn't saw it or we should add more stages
3. Intellectual Property issues
   I used musics on pixbay and unity asset store. All of the drawings are by me
   Also it says "Made with Unity" when loading. That might be a problem. Isn't it?
4. Quality issues
   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m-GCFuNo-9fMcs1XUzFHr6GQitRiZm0n/view?usp=sharing
   this is my game but I set the screen ratio as Free Aspect so it might be wierd but
   it shows good on crazygames q&a tool.

Comment: Welcome to gamedev stack exchange. Is there a question in there (apart from (3), which I'm not qualified to answer)? Assuming that CrazyGames didn't give feedback with their rejection, it looks like you have found some potential issues to consider fixing. If you haven't already done so, consider finding yourself some playtesters (this isn't the forum for that).

Comment: thanks but I have no idea of the policy and I want to know why my game is rejected. Of course, crazygames didn't told me WHY when I contacted them.... So I wanted to ask you guys from feedbacks... dang....

Comment: The [CrazyGames quality guidelines](https://docs.crazygames.com/general/quality-guidelines/) can be found from the links at the bottom of their homepage. On tutorial 3 (which I reached in under 30 seconds of playtesting), *any* amount of movement I applied resulted in "too far." CrazyGames guidelines expect that "errors don't hinder the experience." While there may be other issues, I would certainly consider what I found to be a quality problem with respect to their guidelines.

Comment: And I don't think a made by unity loading screen is getting you rejected, that's the standard for the free version

Comment: These are my personal opinions on the game:
- The game is extremely simple, and not very fun after long periods of time.
- The game feels very unfinished, there is an inconsistent pixel art style (the background is more pixelated than the car for example). And most notibly there is no main menu or any menu. For me, I had to close the game through task manager which is quite a big problem.
- No way to pick levels or see which level you're on.
- No UI or way to see which way you've swiped or how much power.

Honestly the game feels very rushed and low effort which is probably the reason.

Comment: @Pow I showed which level that you are on through the ui on left-up but that seems not be enough isnt it? Since there is less levels (22 Levels on normal, 24 Levels on Challenge) I didn't saved level through playerprefs. Do you think it is okay? And I know it has simple rules, but I am wondering which level you had played to.

Comment: Wait didn't crazygames plays the game and browsers? Can't we simply close tabs to exit? If we make a exit button, should that close the tab in the browser?

Comment: Even so, there should still be a main menu and some kind of level select screen. Perhaps take a look at other similar games on their site to see what you're missing